# How to define a variable in a function and access and change it in another function?(c++)

Tags: c++, function, variables

I would like to know how to define a variable in one function and access and change it in another function. 
For example:

```
#include <iostream>

void GetX()
{
   double x = 400;
}

void FindY()
{
   double y = x + 12;
}

void PrintXY()
{
   std::cout << x;
   std::cout << y;
}

int main()
{
   GetX();
   FindY();
   PrintXY();
}
```

**How would I access these variables from all the functions?** (Obviously for this to work in real life I wouldn't need so many functions, but I think this is a nice simple example). **Thanks in advance for your help!**

Comment: globals? but it's definitively a bad idea... just return it and pass as parameters the values

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda new to c++... how would I do this? Thanks!

Comment: The variables don't exist outside the function anyway.  For example, `x` only exists when `GetX()` is entered, and cease to exist when `GetX()` returns.

Comment: Look up c++ classes.

Comment: ```double x``` and ```double y``` is only exist while the function is running because it is local variable .. if you want to make it exist after the function returns, make it as ```static``` or global variable.. then, you can return it's pointer to be accessed outside the function..

Comment: You can't do it, like that. C++ does not work this way. One function can call the other function and pass the variable as a parameter; or employ some other mechanism. But local variables in a function are called "local" precisely for that reason: they are local to that function. The End.

Comment: A `static` variable is similar to a global variable in the sense that there is only one variable which is persistent, but the variable name scope is not visible outside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to define a variable in one function : That means you are making the variable local to that function.

You want to access and change that local variable from another function. This is not usual. Technically possible but can be done with better resource management/design.

*You can make the variable your class member and play with it.

*You can share a variable by making it global as well.

*In Tricky way :

```
double &GetX()
{
    static double x = 400;
    return x;
}

// We are accessing x here to modify y
// Then we are modifying x itself
// Pass x by reference
double &AccessAndChangeX(double& x)
{
    static double y;
    y = x + 12; // We are accessing x here and using to modify y.

    // Let's modify x
    x = 100;
    return y;
}

void PrintXY(double x, double y)
{
    std::cout << x;
    std::cout << y;
}

int main()
{
    double &x = GetX(); // Take the initial value of x. 400.
    double &y = AccessAndChangeX(x);

    //Print initial value of x and value of y(generated using x)
    PrintXY(x, y);  

    // X was modified while AccessAndChangeX(x). Check if x was changed!
    std::cout << "\n" << "What is the value of x now : " << GetX();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use function parameters to pass values to functions and return values to return results:

```
#include <iostream>

double GetX()
{
    return 400;
}

double FindY(double x)
{
    return x + 12;
}

void PrintXY(double x, double y)
{
    std::cout << x;
    std::cout << y;
}

int main()
{
    double x = GetX();
    double y = FindY(x);
    PrintXY(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the question was tagged with `C++`, here is another option:

```
#include <iostream>
class Sample
{
public:
    void FindY()
    {
        y = x + 12;
    }

    void PrintXY()
    {
        std::cout << x;
        std::cout << y;
    }
private:
    double x = 400, y;
};

int main()
{
    Sample s;
    s.FindY();
    s.PrintXY();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1st, make x, y as `static`, so that these exist when the function returns..
2nd, get reference, modify or do something outside the function..

```
#include <iostream>

double &GetX()
{
   static double x = 400;
   return x;
}

double &FindY( double x )
{
    static double y;
    y = x + 12;
    return y;
}

void PrintXY(double x, double y ) 
{
   std::cout << x;
   std::cout << y;
}

int main()
{
   double &x = GetX();
   double &y = FindY( x );
   // Now you can modify x, y, from Now On..
   // .....

   PrintXY( x, y );
}
```

By the way, I donot recommend this style of code..